# Експоненційно чи експонентно?

Tags: вибір-слова, різниця-між-словами

У моїй освіті я пригадую використання тільки першого варіанту, але і другий виглядає коректно і навіть подобається. Чи є між ними різниця? Чи є джерела, які допоможуть визначити який краще використовувати?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Словники й узус

У «Словнику української мови» у 20 томах є обидва слова в потрібному значенні: і [*експоненційний*](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=194196&page=858) ([*-но*](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=215131&page=858)), і [*експонентний*](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=25749&page=858).

На практиці частіше вживається *експоненційний* (*-но*), ніж *експонентний* (*-но*): [78 траплянь у «ГРАК»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac7&queryselector=lemmarow&lemma=%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD.*) проти [11 траплянь у «ГРАК»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac7&queryselector=lemmarow&lemma=%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD.*).

Отже лідер: ***експоненційний* (*-но*)**.

#### Логіка

За логікою мало б бути так:

- *експонента* → *експонентний* (*-но*);
- *експоненція* → *експоненційний* (*-но*).

*Eкспоненція* — рідковживане слово, «Словник української мови» у 20 томах його не містить. Якийсь «Українсько-російський політехнічний словник» без реквізитів ототожнює укр. *експоненція* з рос. *экспоненция*. І рос. *экспоненция*, і укр. *експоненція* вживаються як у непотрібному нам значенні «представлення, вираженість чогось» («експоненція антигенів на клітинах крові», «падежная экспоненция», «ВИЧ-экспоненция»), так і стосовно функції *x*↦*eˣ* (у російській домінує непотрібне нам значення, в українській десь 50 на 50).

Коротко кажучи, логічніше було б уживати прикметник (і прислівник), що відповідає іменнику *експонента*, — ***експонентний* (*-но*)**. Але вживання *експоненційний* (*-но*) загалом можна виправдати існуванням іменника *експоненція*. Хоча я думаю, що насправді причиною вживання *експоненційний* є не іменник *експоненція*, а те, що спочатку утворили російське *экспоненциальный* під впливом англійського [*exponential*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exponential#Noun), а потім утворили  укр. *експоненційний* під впливом рос. *эскпоненциальный* (аналогічно *potential* → *потенциальный* → *потенційний*).

<sub>Також зазначу, що існують слова [*експонент*](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=25748&page=858) (рос. [*экспонент*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&word=%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82)) і [*експонувати*](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=25754&page=858) (рос. [*эскпонировать*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&word=%D1%8D%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)), що мають як потрібні нам значення, так і непотрібні (щоправда для *експонувати* й *эскпонировать* словники чомусь не зазначають потрібного нам значення (при цьому рос. й укр. словники чомусь містять одні й ті самі тлумачення, наче скопійовані під копірку), але на практиці вочевидь ці слова його мають).</sub>